# how to show all image using angular ng-image-slider

Tags: angular

I am using ng-image-slider for sliding image data from API. I have a service for pull all image data. it works perfectly. the code is below.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.htbservicesService.getHtb()
            .subscribe( 
                htbs => {
                   this.senses = htbs.map(Htb => Htb.image);

                   this.imageList = {
                        image: this.senses,
                        thumbImage: this.senses,
                        // alt: 'alt of image',
                        title: this.senses
                     };
                     console.log(this.imageList);
                     console.log("PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP");


              },
                error => reject(error),
                () => resolve("good")
            );
        });
```

the console.log result looks like this image
[api result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2JmM.png)

at the html file, i have tried to show the image like this

```
<ng-image-slider [images]="imageList"></ng-image-slider>
```

unfortunately, it won't show, but the result image on console.log give it 2 image. the question is how to show all image using ng-image-slider or am i miss something? or should i using ngRepeat, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the response that you're getting from your api:

```
this.http.get("/assets/response.json").subscribe(res => {
  const { image, thumbImage, alt, title } = res;
  image.forEach((img, index) => {
    this.imageObject.push({
      image: img,
      thumbImage: thumbImage[index],
      alt: alt[index],
      title: title[index]
    });
  });
});
```

---

> Here's a [**Working CodeSandbox Sample**](https://codesandbox.io/s/ng-image-slider-example-8m8um) for your ref.

Comment: your reference link not shown the all image on carousel too